# Is there a way to load content of each tab in the view using AJAX?

Tags: views, ajax

I've created View to display my content and I'm using Quicktabs module https://drupal.org/project/quicktabs to format the output of this view into the tabs.

[image: example]

Is there a way to load content of each tab in the view using AJAX? I can't see any option.

Comment: Have you checked the "use ajax" setting in Advanced-Tab inside Views settings? http://i.stack.imgur.com/a8uGJ.png

Comment: Yes. But it has no effect on AJAX tabs. Did you try it with this quicktabs module in views?

Comment: No, i use this module only to create quicktabs-blocks where i reference my views. I didn't try it the other way round, sorry, i think i misinterpreted your question.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. The following code worked perfectly for me.

```
jQuery(".quicktabs-wrapper ul a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(this).parents('.quicktabs-wrapper').find('.quicktabs_main  .quicktabs-tabpage').addClass('quicktabs-hide');
    showId = jQuery(this).attr('id').replace("-tab-", "-tabpage-");
    jQuery('#' + showId).removeClass('quicktabs-hide');
    jQuery(this).parent().siblings('li').removeClass('active');
    jQuery(this).parent().addClass('active');
  });
```